# Complaint of vs Complaint for

Tags: meaning, prepositions, word-usage

Another one *of* vs *for* question, here *for* would be the right choice, because its use denotes the function of purpose as I think it's the case here, right ?

> When customers complaint *of* an error scenario.

Comment: I think you mean *complain*. *Complaint* is a noun. And as a dictionary [will tell you](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complain), people complain *about* things, not *of* or *for*.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA *complain of* is somewhat valid, it is an older style use.

Comment: You can also 'complain about . . .'

Comment: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=complain+of%2Ccomplain+about%2Ccomplain+for%2Ccomplain+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: Your example is not a complete sentence. This makes it difficult to tell exactly how you want to use the words.

Answer (score 3):

In normal text, the most frequent prepositions to follow *complain* is either *of* or *about*, with *about* more common in modern usage.  Here’s an OED citation of each version:

> - 1856 Froude *Hist. Eng.* (1858) II. viii. 255 
>    The government could persuade themselves that evils no longer **complained of** had ceased to exist.
> - 1986 *Guardian* 11 Nov. 12/5 
>    The prisoners have **complained about** restrictions on visits, excessive searches and, above all, brutality.

The OED says that *complain for* is obsolete. It meant to lament. Several other possible prepositions now rarely seen occur historically, but have now all become obsolete, or at most, poetic.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you need to learn the difference between "*complain*" (verb) and "*complaint*" (noun).

As a verb, this is the paradigm of "complain":

```
complain -- complained -- complained
```

So "*complaint*" can't be made to act like a verb.

You could change your sentence fragment this way:

> When customers lodge a complaint/ complaints

Either this or just change the verb to "*complain*."

---

About the preposition, the pattern we normally use is:

> complain + (to somebody/ a department) + **about** something

"*Of*" is also possible but not "*for*."