# Which is correct — "complaint by a customer" or "complaint of a customer"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which is correct usage?

> - complaint dated 01.02.2013 **by** a customer
> - complaint dated 01.02.2013 **of** a customer

Comment: The better preposition is _by_.  I'd also change the word ordering: "complaint by a customer dated 01.02.2013". In the future, I'd recommend asking a question like this at the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange. You might want to check it out.

Comment: In the context, *from* would go even better with *dated*.

Comment: Each preposition carries with it a different implication. The choice would depend on the context and what is exactly intended to convey: *by*, *of*, *from*, all are correct and acceptable accordingly.

Comment: Or avoid using a preposition altogether: _customer complaint dated 01.02.2013_.

Comment: Also see  [Complaint of vs complaint for](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76509),

Comment: @J.R.: I dislike your second sentence (Barrie's suggestion is better). I am a customer, and I have at times made complaints; but I don't have a datestamp.

Comment: @TimLymington: Fair enough. I suppose I could've added a comma – that might've helped. I like Barrie's version, too, although, in my head, I can't help but read it in a William Shatner voice, as in: _Captain's Log, Stardate 43125.8._

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, though the second is ambiguous, and there's a reason to favour yet another.

> Complaint by a customer.

The customer made a complaint. It is not necessarily to you, though that would be guessed from context. It might be favoured if you were talking of a complaint made to a consumer association rather than to you.

> Complaint of a customer.

Could mean the customer made a complaint, or could mean someone complained that there was a customer. At as stretch it could mean a complaint about a customer. It would be clear which meaning you meant, but the other possibilities can make it jar slightly.

> Complaint from a customer.

The same as "by a customer", but with a stronger focus on the receiving of the complaint. While it *could* be used of a complaint made to another body (again, e.g. a consumer association), unless this was made clear, it would be understood as a complaint you yourself received.

So, if the records are of complaints directly received, favour *from*. If you are including both direct and indirect complaints, favour *by*.

Answer (score -1):

complaint dated 01.02.2013 **by** a customer

complaint dated 01.02.2013 **of** a customer

**'tis neither**

complaint dated 01.02.2013 **from** a customer

But 'complaint dated 01.02.2013 **of** a customer' would imply that the customer is the subject of the complaint.